# Should I pass View Model to my service, and if yes, how to do it?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, service, autofac

I have a solution, that uses **Autofac**, and I moved some methods from my View Model to the service file. Right now I am facing a problem, where some of the variables in the service methods and refering to VM properties. So I figured out, that maybe I should pass the View Model to the Service.

First of all, I am not sure that I am supposed to do that, for separation of layers and testability. But I am guessing, that it should be no problem with mocking, correct me if I am wrong.

Another thing is that I am not sure yet how to pass the VM to Service. With my current solution, that you can find below, I am getting `StackOverflow` exception on setter of the Model prop. The thing is, that right now it is the best I have and Im out of any new ideas.

Another thing, if passing a VM to the Service layer is an antipattern, how should I refer a VM property from the Service layer? Should I create some Wrapper for this, that VM and Service will refer to it?

The code will be shown on simplified example. **MainViewModel**:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
  {
        private MainViewModel _vm;
        private Person _person;
        private ISomeService _someService;
        public MainViewModel(ISomeService someService)
        {
            _person = new Person();
            _someService = someService;
            Name = "Slim Shady";
            _vm = new MainViewModel(_someService);

            Execute();
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _person.Name;
            }
            set
            {
                _person.Name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private void Execute()
        {
            string dupa = _someService.GetTheName(_vm);
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(dupa);
        }
    }
```

**Model**:

```
public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

**Service**:

```
public interface ISomeService
    {
        string GetTheName(ViewModel.MainViewModel _vm);
    }
    public class SomeService : ISomeService
    {

        public string GetTheName(MainViewModel _vm)
        {
            return _vm.Name;
        }
    }
```

**Autofac**:

```
public class BootStrapper
    {
        public IContainer BootStrap()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            builder.RegisterType<SomeService>()
              .As<ISomeService>().SingleInstance();

            builder.RegisterType<MainWindow>().AsSelf();
            builder.RegisterType<MainViewModel>().AsSelf().SingleInstance();

            return builder.Build();
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**
Need also consider situation, where some other services will also refer to the Name property of Person.

Comment: Usually you wouldn't tightly couple services and view models. What would be better is to provide your view model with an interface (e.g. `IHaveName` which has a `Name` property) and make your service method accept this interface (e.g. `public string GetTheName(IHaveName ihavename)`). This way you don't couple view model and service because both are referenced by interfaces only.

Comment: @ckuri that sounds like pretty nice idea. Thank you.

Comment: @ckuri should my VM implement the `IHaveName` or should I inject it to the constructor?

Comment: I meant implementing the interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FINAL SOLUTION**

in my Service layer I created:

```
public interface IPersonService
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class PersonService : IPersonService
    {
        Person _personModel = new Person();
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _personModel.Name;
            }
            set
            {
                _personModel.Name = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

and modified:

```
public interface ISomeService
    {
        string GetTheName(IPersonService personService);
    }
    public class SomeService : ISomeService
    {

        public string GetTheName(IPersonService personService)
        {
            return personService.Name;
        }
    }
```

So now I inject to my VM both services, and when retrieving name from `SomeService` I am passing injected `PersonServie`:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private IPersonService _personService;
        private ISomeService _someService;
        public MainViewModel(ISomeService someService, IPersonService personService)
        {
            _personService = personService;
            _someService = someService;
            Name = "Slim Shady";

            Execute();
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _personService.Name;
            }
            set
            {
                _personService.Name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private void Execute()
        {
            string dupa = _someService.GetTheName(_personService);
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(dupa);
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(Name);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't know what your final objective is, but with the info I have, I wouldn't inject a service into another service. I'll try to keep things as separated as possible, while using the VM itself to make services communicate with each other. Why does ISomeService need to have GetTheName()? Can't PersonService be a database repository, and deal with getting persons' information?

Comment: It was just raw example, simple Model with one property. Instead of passing `_personService` parameter with `_someService.GetTheName`, what would you pass over there? For me here the positive fact is, that I can redistribute `_personService` to any other service, if I need.

Comment: And Im not sure how two injected services to VM can communicate together with methods?

Comment: OK, I get it now. I don't have an answer for that, it will depend on what you want to do in the end. How you do it here could work; but this specific question is outside of the scope of MVVM/WPF :) In my mind, services should be independent, and if they cannot be, it could be a design issue. The main thing is that you do not pass your VM to your services anymore

Answer (score 2):

I think there's an inversion of responsibilities here.

If your service must produce data, it has to hold this data. This is not the job of the VM.

So in your example, Name is a property of Person, and in turns becomes the result of a getter method in your VM.

I don't know Autofac, but I think you service should hold the Person object, and provide it to the VM (through the IoC).

Still, we're missing contextual information for a complete and suitable answer.

If Person needs to be instanciated in the VM, you could simply, in the VM, tell your service to instantiate it and return it:

```
public MainViewModel(ISomeService someService)
{
    _someService = someService;
    _person = _someService.GetPerson("John");
    //etc
}

public interface ISomeService
{
    Person GetPerson(string name);
}

public class SomeService : ISomeService
{
    private List<Person> personRepository;

    //insert constructor...

    public Person GetPerson(string name)
    {
        return personRepository.Single(person => person.Name == name);
    }
}
```

Put simply, a Service shouldn't know about VMs, or even what a VM is.

Comment: Sounds interesing. What do you think about idea of **ckuri** from comments to the question? And what if some another services will need also refer to the `Name` prop of the `Person`? I have no situation like this, yet, but may happen when I will continue rebuilding the application. I didnt mention about this in my question, the idea came just now.

Comment: Your VM can inject both services, and make them communicate with each other through methods. About ckuri's idea, it doesn't solve the problem: you're still passing the VM as a parameter, which isn't how VMs should be used.

Comment: What do you think about this approach? https://stackoverflow.com/a/56650635/11027921 I am sure, that I can easily mock this.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I pass View Model to my service, and if yes, how to do it?

No, you shouldn't. A service is not supposed to have any dependency upon a view model. It's the other way around.

> Another thing, if passing a VM to the Service layer is an antipattern, how should I refer a VM property from the Service layer?

You don't. The service should return any data that the view model may need, but it shouldn't know anything about the view model type itself.

In your example, the service should just return a string:

```
public string GetTheName()
{
    return "...";
}
```

If this string comes from the view model, it makes no sense to use a service to retrieve it in the first place. Then you could just access `this.Name` in the view model class directly.

If the service manipulates the name `string` somehow, it should accept the `string` as an argument and return another string, e.g.:

```
public string GetTheName(string name)
{
    return name.Trim();
}
```

Comment: I just updated my question with **POSSIBLE SOLUTION?**, I belive that it should be fine now, what do you think?

Comment: @bakunet: What's the purpose of `ISomeService`? It feels superfluous.

Comment: This is just as a simple example. In real life there is more complex class. The point is, that VM modifies some properties of the object, and the Service needs the values of them. General references are same like in the simple example.

Comment: I was wondering what do you think now about this possible solution? I belive, that it separates the layers and is not any kind of anti-pattern, correct me if Im wrong, please.

Comment: The idea of injecting view model with services is both common and good.